# I want to install files to 2 different directories

Tags: installation

I'm new to packaging up files for distribution (preferably via email). Here's what I want to do:

1) User double clicks installation package (possibly an attachment in an Outlook email).

2) Package installs a Word template to a users' startup directory.

3) Package installs another 5 Word templates to a specific folder on the users' C: drive which the installer knows about so doesn't need to ask the user.

4) Package displays a confirmation message to which the user clicks OK.

What's the easiest/best way of doing this using freeware?

Thanks, Helen.

Comment: Lots of tools can be used to generate a setup that installs files to multiple locations, some generate MSI files for Windows Installer, others like InnoSetup don't. If you already have Visual Studio there is a free installer add-in. WiX is free but perhaps overkill for your requirements. Questions that ask "what tool should I use" are frequently voted down or closed, so I recommend you research for a tool that will work, then you'll find tutorials, then when stuck ask a specific question.

Comment: Thanks PhilDW. I had done some research but wasn't finding it easy to determine whether the tools did what I needed them to ... hence asking the more experienced forum community :-)